# Can an ssh client connect to an existing shell running on a remote machine?

Tags: shell, ssh

Whenever I ssh to a remote machine, it always creates a new remote shell.

Can an ssh client connect to an existing shell running on a remote machine?

Comment: No.  That's not how Unix works, in any way shape or form.

Comment: what you can do is run `screen` or `tmux` on the remote server. That allows you to detach and re-attach to a session that has a shell inside it.

Answer (score 3):

No, an ssh client cannot connect to an existing, running shell.

The [Secure Shell Connection Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#page-10) specifies that an interactive session is:

> A session is a remote execution of a program.  The program may be:
>
> - a shell,
> - an application,
> - a system command,
> - or some built-in subsystem.
>
> It may or may not have a tty, and may or may not involve X11 forwarding.  Multiple sessions can be active simultaneously.

It goes on to clarify, in [Starting a Shell or a Command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#page-13) (my emphasis):

> Once the session has been set up, a program is **started** at the remote end.  The program can be a shell, an application program, or a subsystem with a host-independent name.  Only one of these requests can succeed per channel.

The document then illustrates how the client can request (my emphasis again):

- a "shell", which "will request that the user's default shell (typically
  defined in /etc/passwd in UNIX systems) be **started** at the other end", or
- "exec", which "will request that the server **start** the execution of the
  given command.", or
- "subsystem", which "executes a predefined subsystem" (such as sftp)

As a result, an ssh connection can only start a new shell.

As one comment indicated, you could *emulate* the behavior of connecting to an existing shell by creating a `screen` or `tmux` session on the remote side, then connecting to that remote system via `ssh` (creating a new $SHELL instance!), and then using `screen` or `tmux` commands in that new shell to attach to the existing session.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, although this wasn't possible a few years ago.  In recent years, the Linux kernel introduced a new feature called eBPF.  The SSHLog (https://github.com/sshlog/agent) daemon uses this to listen across processes and allow you to connect to other user's SSH sessions.

After installing, first run the command to list all active sessions on the server.

```
mhill@devlaptop:~$ sshlog sessions
  
 User        Last Activity             Last Command               Session Start              Client IP           TTY
mhill           just now              /usr/bin/gcc             2023-04-10 16:16:18        127.0.0.1:58668         17
billy          10 min ago            /usr/sbin/fdisk           2023-04-10 12:11:05        15.12.5.8:58669         32
```

And attach to them:

```
mhill@devlaptop:~$ sshlog attach 32

Attached to TTY 32.  Press CTRL+Q to exit

billy@devlaptop:~$
```

Now you're sharing this remote shell with another user/session.  You can issue commands the same as if it was your own session.