# Is it possible to change the process on the master or slave side of a pseudoterminal pair?

Tags: pseudoterminal

Given a pair of pseudoterminal master and slave, and two processes communicating via them,

- is it possible to change the process on the master side to another process?
- is it possible to change the process on the slave side to another process?

My questions comes from  炸鱼薯条德里克's comment at [Can ssh client connect to an existing shell running on a remote machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503674/can-ssh-client-connect-to-an-existing-shell-running-on-a-remote-machine#comment929347_503674)

> How is the SSH server "connect" to a shell session? It holds the master pty fd and ensure shell use the corresponding slave pty fd as its stdin/stdout/stderr. Does any SSH server provide the functionality of stealing out the corresponding master pty fd of a already running shell session? I don't think so.

Thanks.

Comment: A process holding fd to them, not the process of them. Two processes are possible to hold fds to the same open file description, and so the same pty. I think it's possible, for example, if these processes holding these fds allow you to communicate with them through UNIX domain socket and pass you that fd, then you can get these fd. Or simply `ptrace()` to the process and steal these fd out. But I have no experience of `ptrace()` at all.

Comment: Yes and yes. Of course, it's hacky (you should use a debugger) and you need the right permissions; for the case of ssh, the master side is held by a process running as root. In a script I wrote for one of your question, I was calling ptsname() on the master side of a pty to get the name of its slave side; instead of calling ptsname(), you can call read() or write().

Comment: It's just normally distro setup the kernel that disallow you to steal other process's fd, and most program wouldn't provide such functionality of giving out fd by UDS.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 It's not a "distro thing", it's a permission thing. You have to either have CAP_SYS_PTRACE or be the same user in order to attach to another process and "steal" its fds via SCM_RIGHTS (or simply run ops on them in the context of that process).

Comment: I vaguely remember there's some /sys settings need to be enabled to allow this. And most distro disable that by default, you need to enable that first. Or maybe I'm just wrong @mosvy

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 I never had to turn any switch in order to be able to send fds via SCM_RIGHTS ancillary messages; and if you attach to a process with ptrace(), you can run *any command* in the context of that process, including sending fds via a UNIX socket.